# Why does canonical ensemble have to a finite total energy in equilibrium?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Consider a closed system containing an ideal gas of $N$ particles. I want to derive that assuming the ergodic hypothesis, at equilibrium the system acquiring a macrostate of energy $E_1$ is given by the Boltzmann distribution.

Let us assume that (Huang, *Intro. Statistical Mechanics*, page 156)

$$P(\vec p, \vec q)\propto \mathrm{d} \vec p_{1} \mathrm{~d} \vec q_{1} \Gamma\left(E_{1}\right),$$
where $\vec p, \vec q \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $P(\vec p, \vec q)$ is the probability that the system is in the microstate $(\vec p, \vec q)$ and
$$\Gamma(E_1) := V^N * \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} d^N\vec{p} \delta (H(\vec p) - E_1),$$ i.e phase space volume corresponding to the macrostate $E_1$.

For an ideal gas, $H(\vec p) = \sum_{i=1}^N \vec p_i^2 /2m$, so
$$\Gamma(E_1) = V^N \frac{2*\pi^{3N/2}(2mE_1)^{3N-1}}{(3N/2)!}.$$

However, just looking at how $\Gamma$ scales with $E_1$, you can see that the higher the total energy $E_1$ of the system, the bigger the phase space volume corresponding that energy surface is. Therefore, the maximisation of entropy cannot lead to a finite total energy at equilibrium.

Since there is no contraint on how much energy the system can take from the heat bath, the system will suck more and more energy. But we know that this is not the case. So what have I done wrong above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the entropy of the system which is maximized in equilibrium, but rather the entropy of the system and bath together. As the system acquires more energy, its entropy increases but the entropy of the bath decreases; at some finite value of the system energy, the total entropy of the system and bath will be maximized.

In a technical sense, the bath should be treated as arbitrarily large but finite, to keep its entropy well-defined. Once all calculations have been performed, we can take the limit as the bath size goes to infinity. In this limit, the bath becomes an unlimited source (or sink) of energy which is characterized by a single number, i.e. its temperature.

Comment: That explains why the system has a finite energy at equilibrium. But then how does the Boltzmann distribution arises within in the system?

Comment: @Our The Boltzmann distribution for the system energy is precisely the distribution which maximizes the total entropy (system+bath), subject to the constraint of fixed total energy (system + bath), in the limit as the bath size goes to infinity. The limit ensures that the temperature of the bath is independent of the energy of the system.